# How to use sqlmap while website uses multiple redirects

Tags: vulnerability, sql-injection, sqlmap

I am testing a publicly available site `https://example.com/ebill/login.php` where I fill the form with account number, like 34413271 and a cookie is assigned for later urls to use, then the above URL redirects to `https://example.com/ebill/authentication.php` and finally to `https://example.com/ebill/billinformation.php`. Where data expected data are loaded.

In this case I am testing command like

```
sqlmap.py -u "https://example.com/ebill/login.php" --dbs  --data="username=34413271&login=Login"  -p "username" --method=POST --risk=3 --level=5 --random-agent --threads=10 --tamper=0eunion,apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,appendnullbyte,base64encode,between,binary,bluecoat,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,charunicodeescape,commalesslimit,commalessmid,commentbeforeparentheses,concat2concatws,dunion,equaltolike,equaltorlike,escapequotes,greatest,halfversionedmorekeywords,hex2char,htmlencode,ifnull2casewhenisnull,ifnull2ifisnull,informationschemacomment,least,lowercase,luanginx,misunion,modsecurityversioned,modsecurityzeroversioned,multiplespaces,ord2ascii,overlongutf8,overlongutf8more,percentage,plus2concat,plus2fnconcat,randomcase,randomcomments,schemasplit,sleep2getlock,sp_password,space2comment,space2dash,space2hash,space2morecomment,space2morehash,space2mssqlblank,space2mssqlhash,space2mysqlblank,space2mysqldash,space2plus,space2randomblank,substring2leftright,symboliclogical,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes,uppercase,varnish,versionedkeywords,versionedmorekeywords,xforwardedfor
```

But I am getting message `all tested parameters do not appear to be injectable`

I even tested with no or less tamper script. I used `--dump`, `--threads` and `-o` switch to dump in optimization mode. But no success.

How to use sqlmap for sites like this which uses cookie-based multiple redirects? Or this site is really injection-proof?

Comment: 1) Is the website protected by a Web Application  Firewall(waf)?    2) DON'T use so many tamper scripts, it will break sqlmap. If the Website has a waf, use 1-3 tamper scripts. If it doesnt have a waf, dont use any at all.

Comment: Don't attack any sites you dont have permission to

Comment: Did manual injecting/testing give a hint to an SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: @UndercoverDog I cannot agree more in this instance. The target here is literally the epitome of such instance where privately testing for vulnerabilities IS NOT and NEVER WILL be advised. The target is a public utility company (electricity provider I believe, per google ) maybe even gov-related given the `.gov.` in their vhost. The state of their web portal points to the fact the company is likely struggling on that end, but it still serves and even saves actual people. Prove permission to test, or delete post.

Answer (score 0):

Using too many tamper scripts will normally break SQLmap.
Limit them to 2 or 3 when the Website is protected by a Web Application Firewall. If it isn't, don't use any.

When starting the attack, SQLmap asks you if you want to use the cookies the website assigned to you.
You also get asked if you want to follow the redirect.
So all problems you have should not be an issue.

You can use the switch `--all` to dump all users, databases etc.

If you want to dump only all DBs, you have to enumerate all DBs with `--dbs` and then use `-D [db1],[db2]... --dump`

Use the switch `-o --threads x` (x=amount of threads) to dump more efficient and faster.

Disclaimer: Do **not** Attack Websites you don't have permission to

Comment: It does not work as you say!! I allowed redirect, cookie and all types of database type, but all went in vain. Even the sqlmap commad ran for days!!

Comment: Did you use less tamper Scripts? And is the Website protected by a waf?

Comment: Yes tried with only first 3 tamper and no WAF as wafw00f says!!

Comment: You normally Dont need any tamper when Theres No waf

Comment: Also did you even manually Test wether the Website is even vulnerable or not?

Comment: I updated the question. No manual testing. But sometimes manual fails while sqlmap succeedes.

Comment: This does not answer the question and neither do for the bounty.

Comment: Then the website is then probably a false positive and nobody here can help you lol